# Having trouble joing to tables with different Column names. I have a Foreign key relationship between the tables but table A will not Join table B

Tags: sql

My table names are `Donut_Order` and `Order_History`. `Donut_Order` has the data I want to JOIN to `Order_History`. Here's my code:

```
SELECT DonutOrder_Id 
FROM Donut_Order
LEFT JOIN Order_History ON Donut_Order.Donut_ID = Order_History.DO_ID;
```

It always returns the `DonutOrder_ID` column with data, not the join on the `Order_history` table with the date in `DO_ID` column.

Comment: This is why you name your columns the same in every table and don't abbreviate, so you can be sure joins are correct by the fact that the join uses the same-named column on both sides. Are you sure that `Donut_ID` is the key from the donut order table? It seems like it would be what donut was ordered... or is it just named deceptively? `Donut_ID` = `DO.ID`? Also, please use aliases, it will be SO much easier to understand your queries.

Comment: `Donut_ID` is not the `DonutOrder_ID` thats you are getting wrong items. I suspect `Donut_ID` is for what type of Donut it is not for the `OrderID` of that donut. Just Change `ON Donut_Order.Donut_ID = Order_History.DO_ID;` to `ON Donut_Order.DonutOrder_ID = Order_History.DO_ID`. And Yes as @ErikE stated, please use aliasing to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Your SELECT clause is selecting the DonutOrder_Id column from your Donut_Order table. You can SELECT * to grab all of the columns, or change your select to only return the columns you want.

Best practice for SQL JOINS is to alias your tables like so:

```
SELECT a.ColumnName, b.ColumnName
FROM TableA a 
    LEFT JOIN TableB b ON b.Id = a.Id
```

That way you don't have any confusion as to which tables the columns have come from

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   do.*,
   oh.*
FROM
   Donut_Order do
   LEFT JOIN Order_History oh
      ON do.DonutOrder_ID = oh.DO_ID;
```

I also changed `Donut_ID` to `DonutOrder_ID`. Let me know if that's incorrect. It might be `do.ID = oh.DO_ID`??? Not sure...

About the name change, this is why you name your columns the same in every table and don't abbreviate, so you can be sure joins are correct by the fact that the join uses the same-named column on both sides. Are you sure that `Donut_ID` is the key from the donut order table? It seems like it would be what donut was ordered... or is it just named deceptively? `Donut_ID` = `DO.ID`? Also, please use aliases as I have done, and it will be SO much easier to understand your queries.